# how to download a file using a java program file that is uploaded in a website

Tags: java, http, cloud, httprequest, httpurlconnection

I have written a java program with `HttpRequest` using `HttpURLConnection` to download/upload a file of any format(`XML`, Image, Documents) from a specific server using it's authentication `API-KEY`. This program works fine. Now i need to upload this `java` program file in to my website as a cloud service and need to be able to download the file from that server using this java program file which is uploaded into this website. How can i do it? One thing to make sure is the `java` program that i wrote is not a web application, it is just a `java` program.

Comment: this question has been covered under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java please investigate in order to get your answer

Comment: i don't want to run the program in my desktop environment. I want to run the java file in a website which then downloads a file.

Answer (score 0):

For Downloading a file Create a function like this as follows:

```
private void exportExcel(HttpServletResponse response, HSSFWorkbook workbook) throws CpaServiceException{
    try{
    response.reset();
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + workbook.getSheetAt(0).getSheetName()+".xls");
    workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
    }catch(IOException e){
        throw new CpaServiceException(CpaConstants.APPLICATION_GENERAL_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Then Call the function as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/"+ControllerPaths.GET_EXCEL_FOR_COMMON_PROCESS_SYSTEM_REPORT, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void getExcelForCommonProcessSystemReport(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, CpaReportFilterDTO filterDTO) throws Exception{
    exportExcel(response, reportService.generateExcelForReport(filterDTO));
}
```

The above code is a sample one. You can do it the similar way to download a document form the browser.

Comment: I wrote the whole program already and is working fine in my PC environment but now i want to run this java file in a website of mine. When i run this in that website then it should download file from another server website to my PC. This is what i'm asking for.